# Angular deploy to azure failed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, azure, deployment

I have angular app that I need to deploy to Azure

I deploy it via VS Code Azure App Service extension

App Service is Node LTS 10 and here is config for it

[image]

Here is startup command

`pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa`

After deploy vscode output says this

```
11:02:21 AM meetmymonsterreserve: Deployment successful.
```

11:02:30 AM: Deployment to "meetmymonsterreserve" completed.

But when I go to https://meetmymonsterreserve.azurewebsites.net/

I got this in console

[image]

At local project works well

Where can be a problem?

Comment: How about Node 12 LTS？

Comment: Do you need custom startup command? The container automatically starts your app with PM2 when one of the common Node.js files is found in your project. https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs#run-with-pm2

Comment: Already fixed this stuff, maybe smth wrong with VS Code plugin, as it is in preview. I deploying it via Azure Pipelines CI/CD and all okay @JasonPan

Comment: This article recommends that the Runtime Stack should be .NET Core: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/easily-deploy-angular-app-to-azure-from-visual-studio-code/