# My Angular 10 App deployed in Azure is loosing its styles when refreshed

Tags: css, azure-web-app-service, angular10, devextreme-angular

I have started working on an Angular 10 application using DevExtreme UI Widgets. I deployed a demo version in our Azure Cloud but while I was playing with it, I noticed a strange behavior. It seems that I lose my styles when I refresh.
For example, this is how the login page should be displayed:

[image: Good Login Page]

If I refresh the URL without entering my login credentials, the page changes and gets displayed like this:

[image: Bad Login Page]

When I login, the bad or good styles are carried over. For example, the landing page should be displayed like this:

[image: Good landing page]

If I refresh the screen here, I also see the styles being altered. This is how the landing page gets displayed when the styling is lost:

[image: Bad landing page]

When I lose the styling if I keep refreshing the page over and over again, eventually I regain the styles and my application starts being displayed as intended.

Any idea what causes the styles to be lost? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: What method did you use for deployment?

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks again for wanting to help. I use the Azure App Service Visual Studio Code extension to deploy my app. The first time the app was deployed, I set-up the Web App in my Azure Portal followed steps described in this article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/easily-deploy-angular-app-to-azure-from-visual-studio-code/. One thing that is different from many other articles I looked at at that time is that the recommended Runtime Stack is .NET Core and not Node. That worked for me, except these lost styles. Let me know if you need to know any parameters for my Azure Web App.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the deployment of Angular projects, I have encountered various problems. I am willing to share it with you and hope it will help you.

***Troubleshooting steps:***

**Solution 1.**

You can deploy it via Azure Pipelines CI/CD without using the vscode to deploy webapp.

[Maybe smth wrong with VS Code plugin, as it is in preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64314074/angular-deploy-to-azure-failed#comment113733776_64314074)

**Solution 2.**

Use github for continuous deployment. It is recommended to create a webapp and choose the Linux operating system.

**Solution 3.**

It is recommended to use FTP to publish the `build` folder after the project `npm build`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will look into them. We are using TFS for source code repository, but I know that it can also be used for CI/CD. I was thinking that it is a setting of some sort, as the files are copied properly.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved. After further investigation, it turns out that the problem had nothing to do with Azure Cloud deployment. I use DevExtreme UI widgets in my application and the application is based on their [Angular Template](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Angular_Components/Application_Template/).

I tried the website using Chrome, Edge and Firefox. The issue described above only happened in Chrome. DevExpress tech support pointed me to [this support ticket](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t917577/devextreme-does-not-attach-additional-classes-to-dx-viewport-in-chrome-84-on-the-first).

After following the recommendations in the workaround and a redeployment, my app looks fine even in Chrome.

Thanks for everyone trying to help.
Ed